# Understanding the transition map in the case of the proof that $S^3$ bundles over $S^4$

Tags: functions, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Here is the part of the paper of "Rachel Mcenroe" on Milnor's construction of Exotic 7-spheres:

> [image]

But I do not understand why the transition map is $\frac{1}{z}$ and it does not include any $\omega.$ Could anyone help me in understanding this ,please?

Comment: Your edit is not so much an "edit" as a "new question", and generally speaking we like to ask that you have [one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry about that ..... I will post my edit as another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, they have simply used a variable substitution $w=\frac{1}{z}$, from which one computes
$$\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}(z) = \phi_2 (\phi_1^{-1}(z)) = \phi_2([z;1]) = \phi_2([\frac{1}{w};1]) = \phi_1([1;w]) = w = \frac{1}{z}
$$

Comment: Oh, and there is no relation between the $\omega$ in the substitution and the $\omega$ in the paper .... right?

Comment: The paper has a $w$, my answer has a $w$, and they are the same $w$. Keep in mind, these are free variables. There is no $\omega$ in the paper extract in your post; perhaps you misread it.

Comment: I think there is $\omega$ in $\phi_2$ in the paper extract in my post or this is $w$?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misread it, yes.